# Why does the htmlentities function not properly work?

Tags: php, html-entities

I tried the `htmlentities()` function with PHP 5 with this code:

```
<?php
 $string="Einstürzende Neubauten"; echo htmlentities($string);
?>
```

And it only displays two whitespaces (i.e. "  "). Why is that? I tried to replace the "u with diaeresis" char with another and it works. How can i get that work too?

Comment: right click and view page view source its working.

Comment: yep, works for me was well

Comment: maybe an encoding problem. have you tried `meta charset=utf-8`?

Comment: I tried with utf-8 , and the source doesn't contain the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use charset for your given content to .... eg

```
 $res = htmlentities ( $string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

For more informations take a look [in the manual htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlentities.php)

Which PHP-Version did you use?

maybe this could be a solution for you

```
 $string = mb_convert_encoding ($str , "UTF-8");
 // testing 
    var_dump($string);
 $res = htmlentities ( $string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
 // testing
    var_dump($res);
```

See [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

Comment: Anyway, thanks. It was the .php file that was encoded in ANSI (by default with notepad in Windows). I changed it, set up in the php and apache configuration the UTF-8 encoding too and now all works.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem when I upgraded the PHP version from 5.2 to 5.6. I wrote:

```
$res = htmlentities("Producción", ENT_IGNORE);
```

And I got

```
Produccin
```

but I solved it, adding this after connect to database

```
mysqli_set_charset($idCon,'utf8');
```